# Unable to deploy a .mjs file using CDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, es6-modules

I'm trying to create a Nodejs Lambda project locally in vscode, which I'm going to deploy using CDK. I start by running

```
cdk init app --language javascript
```

At some point in my development I'm going to want to use EC6 modules, so I will need to add "type":"module" into my package.json

If I run cdk synth now, I start to get these errors:

file:///E:/Code/Github/VBG/dnclistimporter/bin/dnclistimporter.js:3
const cdk = require('aws-cdk-lib');
^

> ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use
> import instead This file is being treated as an ES module because it
> has a '.js' file extension and
> 'E:\Code\Github\VBG\dnclistimporter\package.json' contains "type":
> "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the
> '.cjs' file extension.

Fair enough, so I change my requires to imports, so in my importer.js file this

> const cdk = require('aws-cdk-lib'); const { DnclistimporterStack } =
> require('../lib/dnclistimporter-stack');
>
> const app = new cdk.App(); new DnclistimporterStack(app,
> 'DnclistimporterStack', {});

becomes this

> import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
> import { DncListImporterStack } from '../lib/dnclistimporter-stack';
> const app = new cdk.App();
> new DnclistimporterStack(app, 'DnclistimporterStack', {});

and now I'm getting the following error message

> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'E:\Code\Github\VBG\dnclistimporter\lib\dnclistimporter-stack' imported from E:\Code\Github\VBG\dnclistimporter\bin\dnclistimporter.js

It's the same code, just imported using import not require, but it doesn't find the module. I rename the .js to .mjs and now it gives

> SyntaxError: The requested module '../lib/dnclistimporter-stack.mjs' does not provide an export named 'DncListImporterStack'

It's the same code, just had the file renamed to .mjs:

> const { Stack, Duration } = require('aws-cdk-lib'); class
> DnclistimporterStack extends Stack {
>
> constructor(scope, id, props) {
> super(scope, id, props);  } }
>
> module.exports = { DnclistimporterStack }

I change the require to an import:

```
import { Stack } from 'aws-cdk-lib'

class DnclistimporterStack extends Stack {
 
  constructor(scope, id, props) {
    super(scope, id, props);

  }
}

module.exports = { DnclistimporterStack }
```

But get the same error. What am I doing wrong and is there a better way of setting up an AWS Lambda project (apart from an AWS SAM app which requires docker and I can't install that because I'm working on a VM)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Perhaps that's your issue.

You are exporting "DnclistimporterStack" but are importing "DncListImporterStack"